# How I can reference a field defined in the gradle script?

Tags: groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I have a script to prepare build of an apk.

It defines some value which has some random specific for each build value:

```
def salt = generateSalt()

def generatedSalt() {
 return generateRandomlySalt
}
```

In the same script I want to have another method which will operate on this value.

```
def generateMapAndSalt() {
  // here is additional logic which depends on the defined salt
  generateEncodedHash(certificate, salt, shaKey)
}
```

There is another method inside of android closure which will pass this defined salt value to the buildConfigFiles.
How do I reference once generated salt value from defined method?
Tired accessing it with following syntax:

```
this.$salt
$salt
salt
```

With no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the salt in an `ext` block and refer to it via `project` instance.

```
ext {
   salt = generateSalt()
}

project.salt
```

Comment: Thanks, that is it.

I was able to skip the project. reference as well - do you know why?

Comment: Because gradle by default looks for a property in a `project` scope. If it's not defined there, then the problem occurs.

Comment: To add to this, *everything* in the build script will try and use the project object, even things like `apply plugin: 'foo'`, it's just running `project.apply()` and passing in the map values `plugin: 'foo'`. Similarly for the `dependencies` configuration etc. Hence why I always have https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html open